# Как сделать, чтобы картинка не дергалась?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Нужна Ваша помощь по верстке. Как сделать, чтобы [картинка](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua) не дергалась?

[alt text http://u.askdev.ru/545/6053/c1d455/medium.gif](http://u.askdev.ru/545/6053/c1d455/medium.gif)

Comment: А если img задать один размер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Смените слайдер...** он на специфичных переходах просто криво режет/складывает кусочки фоток.
*Фотки можно было б одного размера сделать*.

В общем, на простых эффектах типа fadeIn все гуд...

```
.vt_module_content li img {margin: 0;padding: 0;float: left;width: 100%;}
.vt_module_content li {float: left;width: 100%;}
.vt_module_content {float: left;height: 164px;overflow: hidden;padding: 5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, дело в border. Задайте `img {border:0px} и img:hover{border:0px}``

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk не помогло, к сожалению.